# addEventListener() error while using ZingTouch in ReactJs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, frameworks

I'm simply trying to add zingtouch as an event listener to my code. I need to add a 'rotate' event listener to the wheel component. I used componentDidMount() so that html elements can be fetched after the Wheel component is added. Not just that i'm unable to use any simple .addEventListener('click') to this code as it gives me the same error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.addEventListener is not a function
    at Region.js:86:1
```

Here is the source code for the wheel component.

```
import React from 'react';
import "./Wheel.css";
import ZingTouch from "zingtouch";

class Wheel extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        const wheel = document.getElementsByClassName('wheel');
        const region = new ZingTouch.Region(wheel);
        region.bind(wheel, 'rotate', (e)=>{
            console.log('rotating', e);
        })
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wheel">
        <span className="menu-button">MENU</span>
        <button className="select-button">SELECT</button>
        <span className="material-symbols-outlined play-pause">play_pause</span>
        <span className="material-symbols-outlined fast-forward">
          fast_forward
        </span>
        <span className="material-symbols-outlined fast-rewind">
          fast_rewind
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Wheel;
```

Comment: There is no `addEventListener` in the code you provided. Can you add an example of how you are trying to use it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.